# How to detect mouseenter and leave on parent element in this specific case

Tags: jquery

I use this code to apply image effects on hover/mouse out but I do not want the mouseover /out to be attached to image directly because there's an overlay that appears on top,

```
jQuery('.gridfx-img img').each(function(){
    this.onmouseout = function(){
        var canvas1 = Pixastic.process(this, "desaturate");
        canvas1.onmouseover = function(){
            Pixastic.revert(this);
        }
    }
    this.onload = function(){
        var canvas = Pixastic.process(this, "desaturate");
        canvas.onmouseover = function(){
            Pixastic.revert(this);
        }
    }
});
```

The element I am targetting is .gridfx-img mouse enter / leave however If i changed that, the code does not work. because this has to be the actual image. I tried this.parents() etc nothing worked so far. any ideas?

Comment: for specific case as here, you should provide a jsfiddle to let us see more on what's going on

Comment: What is Pixastic? Would you mind to put us into context?

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you really. Either you can attach your event to your overlay, and then use jQuery traversing functions to navigate from that element to your child image that you want to effect.

Alternatively, and probably more likely, you want to turn off mouse events for your overlay. That will allow rollovers and click throughs to pass through the layer and to your image that you want to effect. It's done in CSS rather than jquery itself - depend if your overlay has any mouse functionality.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
#overlay {    
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method will return the ancestor of the node matching the selector. The [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method accepts 2 methods to handle the mouse in and mouse out events.

```
var container = jQuery('.gridfx-img img').closest(".gridfx-img").hover(
    function onMouseInDo(event){},
    function onMouseOutDo(event){},
)
```